# Java Line2d.double how to set the stroke

Tags: java, graphics2d, java-2d

Hello I have an application where you click one point and then anotherand it draws a line that has a stroke of 20. I want to be able to click any part of the line and delete it.

```
private Shape line = new Line2D.Double(x, y, fx, fy);

public highlight(int x, int y, int fx, int fy, int page, boolean fin) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.fx = fx;
    this.fy = fy;

    line = new Line2D.Double(x, y, fx, fy);

    this.fin = fin;

    this.page = page;
}

public void tick() {
    line = new Line2D.Double(x, y, fx, fy);

    if (!fin) {
        play.cannotdrawline = true;
        fx = Comp.mx;
        fy = Comp.my;
    } else {
        play.cannotdrawline = false;

    }

    if(line.intersects(Comp.mx,Comp.my,1,1) && play.candeleteline){
        if(Comp.ml){
            remove = true;
        }
    }
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));

    // g.setColor(new Color(190,240,93, 143));
    if (line.intersects(Comp.mx, Comp.my,1,1) && play.candeleteline) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.red);

    }
    g.drawLine(x, y, fx, fy);
    //g2d.draw(line);

}
```

}

This all works fine, I can delete it but I have to click one the very middle line of pixels to be able to delete it. I know how to set the stroke for drawing a line but I don't know how to set the stroke for the line shape (which is the part that checks if you can delete the line or not). How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to set the stroke for drawing a line but I don't know how to set the stroke for the line shape (which is the part that checks if you can delete the line or not). How can I do this?

As far as I know, you can't since, similar to Color, the Stroke is a property of the Graphics2D object and not of the Shape. You can however associate a certain Stroke with certain Shape using a Map, or using a custom class if need be, for instance if you need to associate multiple properties such as Stroke and Color with Shape, just like any other Java association could be made.